# Differences between Marathon and Chronos

Tags: mesos, marathon

In an Apache **Mesos cluster**, both **Marathon** (for long-running tasks) and 
**Chronos** (for scheduled tasks) can be used to schedule jobs.
Why we need two different schedulers- one for for long running tasks and  another one for scheduled tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer I was looking for :

**Marathon** is used for long running(hence the name 'Marathon') tasks:
`'long running tasks'` starts but never ends.
Mesos will ensure that applications it has launched will continue running, even if the slave node(s) they are running on fails.
Example for a long running service:a web server

**Chronos** is used for scheduled tasks:
eg:ETL jobs
`Scheduled tasks` has defined start time and end time.
I may not want a failing scheduled tasks to restart again and again.
In chronos we can add dependent jobs to start upon completion of previous jobs,
building arbitrary DAGs(Directed Acyclic Graph) of jobs,which is the case with most ETL jobs.

References:
https://aster.is/blog/2015/10/07/whats-a-long-running-task/
[How to run a one-off task with Apache Mesos/Marathon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937978/how-to-run-a-one-off-task-with-apache-mesos-marathon)
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/marathon-framework/DPQfTN_3ssY
[Mesos Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458504/mesos-framework)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is well documented:

- https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/
- https://github.com/mesos/chronos

To generalize: Marathon is for long-running tasks (i.e. services), whereas Chronos is for scheduled tasks (i.e., `cron`-like jobs).

Comment: I knew Marathon is used for long running tasks.I should have asked "Why Marathon is used for services and chronos for scheduled tasks(and difference between Services vs Scheduled tasks)".Since this question doesn't have good quality, will delete it soon.